# Apply gghighlight to multiple facets of time series plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, gghighlight

For the dataset `df` (the data is posted in the end of this question), I try to use `gg_season()` and `gghighlight(year >= 2020)` to highlight the lines after the years of 2020.

But the output is obviously not as expected, how could I modify to `year >= 2020` to achieve the correct effect of plot? Thanks.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(feasts)
library(tsibble)
library(gghighlight)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, origin = "1899-12-30")) %>% 
  mutate(year=year(date)) %>%
  pivot_longer(`food_index`:`energy_index`) %>% 
  mutate(date=yearmonth(date)) %>%
  as_tsibble(index=date, key=name) %>%
  gg_season(value, alpha=1) +
  geom_line(size=0.8, alpha=0.8) +
  geom_point(size=2, alpha=1) +
  gghighlight(year >= 2020)
```

Out:

[image]

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(date = c(42766, 42794, 42825, 42855, 42886, 42916, 
42947, 42978, 43008, 43039, 43069, 43100, 43131, 43159, 43190, 
43220, 43251, 43281, 43312, 43343, 43373, 43404, 43434, 43465, 
43496, 43524, 43555, 43585, 43616, 43646, 43677, 43708, 43738, 
43769, 43799, 43830, 43861, 43890, 43921, 43951, 43982, 44012, 
44043, 44074, 44104, 44135, 44165, 44196, 44227, 44255, 44286, 
44316, 44347, 44377, 44408, 44439, 44469, 44500, 44530, 44561
), food_index = c(58.53, 61.23, 55.32, 55.34, 61.73, 56.91, 54.27, 
59.08, 60.11, 66.01, 60.11, 63.41, 69.8, 72.45, 81.11, 89.64, 
88.64, 88.62, 98.27, 111.11, 129.39, 140.14, 143.44, 169.21, 
177.39, 163.88, 135.07, 151.28, 172.81, 143.82, 162.13, 172.22, 
176.67, 179.3, 157.27, 169.12, 192.51, 194.2, 179.4, 169.1, 193.17, 
174.92, 181.92, 188.41, 192.14, 203.41, 194.19, 174.3, 174.86, 
182.33, 182.82, 185.36, 192.41, 195.59, 202.6, 201.51, 225.01, 
243.78, 270.67, 304.57), energy_index = c(127.36, 119.87, 120.96, 
112.09, 112.19, 109.24, 109.56, 106.89, 109.35, 108.35, 112.39, 
117.77, 119.52, 122.24, 120.91, 125.41, 129.72, 135.25, 139.33, 
148.6, 169.62, 184.23, 204.38, 198.55, 189.29, 202.47, 220.23, 
240.67, 263.12, 249.74, 240.84, 243.42, 261.2, 256.76, 258.69, 
277.98, 289.63, 293.46, 310.81, 318.68, 310.04, 302.17, 298.62, 
260.92, 269.29, 258.84, 241.68, 224.18, 216.36, 226.57, 235.98, 
253.86, 267.37, 261.99, 273.37, 280.91, 291.84, 297.88, 292.78, 
289.79)), row.names = c(NA, 60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
#install.packages("feasts")
library(feasts)
#> Loading required package: fabletools
library(tsibble)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tsibble'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:lubridate':
#> 
#>     interval
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, union
library(gghighlight)

df <- structure(list(date = c(42766, 42794, 42825, 42855, 42886, 42916, 
                              42947, 42978, 43008, 43039, 43069, 43100, 43131, 43159, 43190, 
                              43220, 43251, 43281, 43312, 43343, 43373, 43404, 43434, 43465, 
                              43496, 43524, 43555, 43585, 43616, 43646, 43677, 43708, 43738, 
                              43769, 43799, 43830, 43861, 43890, 43921, 43951, 43982, 44012, 
                              44043, 44074, 44104, 44135, 44165, 44196, 44227, 44255, 44286, 
                              44316, 44347, 44377, 44408, 44439, 44469, 44500, 44530, 44561
), food_index = c(58.53, 61.23, 55.32, 55.34, 61.73, 56.91, 54.27, 
                  59.08, 60.11, 66.01, 60.11, 63.41, 69.8, 72.45, 81.11, 89.64, 
                  88.64, 88.62, 98.27, 111.11, 129.39, 140.14, 143.44, 169.21, 
                  177.39, 163.88, 135.07, 151.28, 172.81, 143.82, 162.13, 172.22, 
                  176.67, 179.3, 157.27, 169.12, 192.51, 194.2, 179.4, 169.1, 193.17, 
                  174.92, 181.92, 188.41, 192.14, 203.41, 194.19, 174.3, 174.86, 
                  182.33, 182.82, 185.36, 192.41, 195.59, 202.6, 201.51, 225.01, 
                  243.78, 270.67, 304.57), energy_index = c(127.36, 119.87, 120.96, 
                                                            112.09, 112.19, 109.24, 109.56, 106.89, 109.35, 108.35, 112.39, 
                                                            117.77, 119.52, 122.24, 120.91, 125.41, 129.72, 135.25, 139.33, 
                                                            148.6, 169.62, 184.23, 204.38, 198.55, 189.29, 202.47, 220.23, 
                                                            240.67, 263.12, 249.74, 240.84, 243.42, 261.2, 256.76, 258.69, 
                                                            277.98, 289.63, 293.46, 310.81, 318.68, 310.04, 302.17, 298.62, 
                                                            260.92, 269.29, 258.84, 241.68, 224.18, 216.36, 226.57, 235.98, 
                                                            253.86, 267.37, 261.99, 273.37, 280.91, 291.84, 297.88, 292.78, 
                                                            289.79)), row.names = c(NA, 60L), class = "data.frame")

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, origin = "1899-12-30")) %>% 
  mutate(year = year(date)) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(food_index, energy_index)) %>% 
  mutate(date = yearmonth(date)) %>%
  as_tsibble(index = date, key = name) %>%
  gg_season(y = value, alpha = 1) +
  geom_line(size = 0.8, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% filter(date == max(date)),
            aes(label = year, x = date, y = value + 10),
            check_overlap = TRUE) +
  gghighlight(calculate_per_facet = TRUE, year >= 2020,
              use_direct_label = FALSE, unhighlighted_params = list(label = NULL))
#> Warning: Tried to calculate with group_by(), but the calculation failed.
#> Falling back to ungrouped filter operation...
#> Warning: Using `across()` in `filter()` is deprecated, use `if_any()` or
#> `if_all()`.
#> Warning: Tried to calculate with group_by(), but the calculation failed.
#> Falling back to ungrouped filter operation...
#> Warning: Using `across()` in `filter()` is deprecated, use `if_any()` or
#> `if_all()`.
#> Warning: Tried to calculate with group_by(), but the calculation failed.
#> Falling back to ungrouped filter operation...
#> Warning: Using `across()` in `filter()` is deprecated, use `if_any()` or
#> `if_all()`.

#> Warning: Using `across()` in `filter()` is deprecated, use `if_any()` or
#> `if_all()`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, it's close. To make it more perfect, I'm considering two issues in your output: 1. different from the upper one, the lower subplot has no indicators of year, 2. for both two subplots, the grey lines without indicators we don't know, it belongs to which year. Any ideas to solve these two problems?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show one potential solution @ahbon. I'm not sure how else you could do it